# Find first word in html and replace

Tags: html, split

I have following construct:

```
<h1>
  <span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

....
and

```
<div id="tourname">Riding trip arround the volcano</div>
```

Now the div with the id is filled by a php function and I would like that
my h1 looks like this:

```
<h1>
   <span>Riding</span>
   trip arround the volcano
</h1>
```

I managed to fill the h1 using this function:

```
 $("h1").html($("#tourname").html());
```

but I have no idea how to split my string into 2 parts and fill one part
into that span and the rest behind the /span

Can you give a hint ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in 2 ways . 
1 - When you are writing using php , you can create the span for first word.
2 - Using jQuery. You can see the below code using jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $("#tourname").html();
    var firstword = text.substr(0,text.indexOf(' ')); // to get the first word 
    var remaining = text.substr(text.indexOf(' ')+1); // remianing words
    var final = '<span>'+firstword+'</span> '+ remaining // combining by adding <span> around the first word
    $("h1").html(final);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Azeez, I tested it, but somewhere there seems to be an error, I couldn't get that working.

Comment: Where you are finding issues?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 var strArr = $("#tourname").html().split(' '); 
 $("h1 span").html(strArr.shift());
 $("h1").append(document.createTextNode(strArr.join(" ")));
```

This should be of some help.
Also consider this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0aghb4k/1/)

This will be specific to your use only.
For more flexibility with number of text elements use `strArr.splice(index, number_of_elements_to_include_in_span);`
 instead of `strArr.shift();`